# Need help solving exponential equation $2\mathrm{e}^x=5-\mathrm{e}^{-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help solving $2\mathrm{e}^x=5-\mathrm{e}^{-x}$.

I've tried many ways of solving it but I keep getting the wrong answer.

By the way, my book says the solutions are $x=-1.518$ and $x=0.825$

Thanks!

Comment: The answers, *rounded* to 3.d.p., will be $-1.518$ and $0.825$ but they are not the exact answers. In fact, the exact answers will be expressed in terms of logarithms. For example the answer which rounds to $0.825$ is in fact

$$0.82451591412420971886\ldots$$

Where the number carries on for ever. Imagine you had a job and your salary was $44,\! 567.89$ a year and your boss gave you $44,\! 000$ saying that was the same as $44,\! 567.89$; would you accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $y=e^x$. Our equation becomes $2y=5-\dfrac{1}{y}$. With manipulation this becomes a quadratic equation in $y$. Solve for $y$. Then find $x$.

Comment: I just solved it that way. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I had left things for you to do, it is good that with the hint you were able to finish.